# PAF database vs a service such as Postcode Anywhere

Tags: postal-code, paf

Would it be more cost effective for a small business (around 25 concurrent users) to buy a PAF database and code it up ourselves or use a Postcode service such as Postcode Anywhere?

The Royal Mail site is really confusing! http://www.royalmail.com/marketing-services/address-management-unit/address-data-products/postcode-address-file-paf/prices

We operate 24 hours a day and at any one time, we have between 1 and 25 users doing postcode searches. We are currently using a PAYG service and it is really pricey so we want to buy a PAF database and create our own. I don't understand the pricing on the link above (basically we're looking at something in the region of £2 to £49,500?!)

Also, what do you actually get with a PAF database? As in what kind of files do they send you, is there an API and do you pay a one off fee or an ongoing fee? Do you have to agree to the delete the data once you stop paying royal mail?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about database pricing options.

Comment: @Flexo Well it doesn't matter now as it's a three year old question, but I was more asking to try and gauge how easy/difficult the PAF database is to work programatically, and to figure out whether or not it was worth doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time it would take to code it up yourselves, it would be more time and cost efficient to go with someone like Postcode Anywhere.  They'll also provide guaranteed first class service along with service updates to improve service.

We use them on a lesser-scale (after moving from QAS which were crap in comparison).
Have you investigated pricing with any providers yet - if so, what's it coming out at?

I can't add anymore to the answer by Alan, which describes how the files are provided and how it needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You get a bunch of flat files and need to use the PAF programmers guide to help build yourself a system
http://www.royalmail.com/marketing-services/address-management-unit/address-data-products/programmers-guide

See also
www royalmail.com/sites/default/files/docs/pdf/01_tell_me_the_basics.pdf
www royalmail.com/pafnews

You're probably better off buying some package www poweredbypaf.com/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to purchase the Royal Mail Postcode Address File (PAF). There are lots of API's available.

getAddress.io is the only one I've found that's free:

[https://getAddress.io](http://getAddress.io)

Comment: Wish this service had been available three years ago, would have saved me a lot of hassle, thanks though :)

Comment: I don't see a declaration as Licensed Royal Mail Solutions Provider on that site.

Comment: Who cares? It's the data itself that counts.